# Animate a UITextField when changing from hidden to visible using AutoLayout

Tags: objective-c

I have a UITextField that is set to hidden, when I click the search button I want to make it visible but I want to create an animation like a slide-in, is it possible to recreate this effect if i'm using autoLayout?

The code I used for the animation is the current (it creates a fade-in effect):

```
if(!currentSrcState)
    {
        _searchField.hidden = NO;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                              delay:0.0
                            options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlDown
                         animations:^ {
                             _searchField.alpha = 1.0;
                         }
                         completion:nil];
        currentSrcState = YES;
    }
    else
    {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                              delay:0.0
                            options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlDown
                         animations:^ {
                             _searchField.alpha = 0;
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){
                             _searchField.hidden = YES;
                         }];

        currentSrcState = NO;
    }
```

What I want to acheive is that when the `_searchField` is hidden the constraint gets recalculated in order to move what is under the searchField up

Comment: have you tried animating the frame of `_searchField` along with the `.alpha`?

Comment: I tried setting height to 0 but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Instead of set the button to hidden, set its alpha value to 0.0 before load the view. Then change your code to:

```
if(!currentSrcState)
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                          delay:0.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlDown
                     animations:^ {
                         _searchField.alpha = 1.0;
                     }
                     completion:nil];
    currentSrcState = YES;
}
else
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                          delay:0.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlDown
                     animations:^ {
                         _searchField.alpha = 0.0;
                     }
                     completion:nil];

    currentSrcState = NO;
}
```

Comment: Sorry I think I've explained my problem wrong, the animation works fine, the problem is that the height occupied by the UITextField is still there even if I set it to hidden because it has Constraints, what I want to know is if it's possible to recalculate the constraints in order to have also that kind of animation